# conditional rendering of <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager> possible?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

My site master page contains a single `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>` declaration so that the few pages in my site that use an UpdatePanel need not include such a declaration.  The downside to this approach is that a bunch of useless MS-Ajax JS is being emitted to the client even when it's not being used.

Is there a way to interrogate the page being rendered to see if it contains any controls dependent on the ToolkitScriptManager, and not render it in that case?

Thanks.